# NVIDIA GT860m GPU clock stuck at 33Mhz after resume from suspend 14.04 -> 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 16.04, suspend

Every time my laptop resumes from suspend GPU performance becomes poor (e.g. glxgears performance test shows ~100 fps while on normal mode it shows around 19k). nvidia-settings' powermiser shows graphic clock at 33Mhz while min graphic clock level apears to be 135Mhz in any mode.
My Graphic Card:

```
description: 3D controller  
product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]  
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
```

I have Ubuntu/Win8 dual boot configuration and this issue only appears at Ubuntu. I've experienced this issue for 2 years, tried all Ubuntu versions from **14.04** to **16.04**. Currently using *nvidia-367* driver(tried a lot of driver versions as well).

The other issue I've experienced (which also may be connected) is that GPU never returns to High performance mode after i disconnect/connect charger. It seems GPU frequency settings just don't return to normal state after adaptive changes. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is nvidia driver bug. See below for details
https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/683